# redirect to another domain without affecting SEO

Tags: apache, .htaccess, seo, subdomain, blogger

I have a blog www.MY_BLOG_NAME.com which is hosted in blogger.com, Its almost 4 year old and have better search engine ranking. Most of the traffic came through Google. 
Now i am redesigning my site in drupal, but i want to keep old blog. New site in `www.MY_BLOG_NAME.com` and old in `old.MY_BLOG_NAME.com`.

Is there anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bad idea to have your old blog and your new blog running at the same time - Google will view this as duplicate content and your ranking will drop.

You can do it if you put a nofollow tag on your old blog, so not bots will be able to index it.

Comment: I second this. If you're re-designing your blog, you should use a 301 re-direct to the new one when it is finished, and at the same time import blogger into Drupal. I'm sure there are tools for that... Essentially, do _not_ keep the old blog. With a 301 re-direct, all ranking that OLD has, will be transferred to NEW.

Comment: @PatrikAlienus this is what i want :) But i dont know much about 301 redirect . Do you have any working example?

Comment: There are lots of resources on the web to learn the basics of 301 redirects on Apache (with an .htaccess file) - you should be able to find some walkthroughs on Google :)

Comment: @zenkaty i have nearly 700 pages so is there a way to apply dynamic 301 redirect? based on the url?

Comment: I think better open as a separate question

Comment: If the article pages are the same, you can do a folder redirect, where all the articles stay the same, and it just changes the first part of the URL. But yeah maybe do some research, have a go yourself at this, and if you get stuck, post another question with specifics :)

Comment: Since you're running Drupal I'm assuming it's on a *nix system? If so, use .htaccess. Like someone else said, there are plenty of resources for it. Have a google.